# How to use button to display data from sqlite flask backend to the front end?

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlite

I am building a front end which displays the row of data from sqlite database. For backend, I am using flask. I have a check button on the front end. What I need to do is to display the data one by one as I click the check button.

Comment: when you click button then it sends request to server (flask) and it should generate new page (full HTML) with data from database and send to browser. This is standard method - it reloads full page. If you need  without reloading page then button should run JavaScript code which use AJAX (XHR) to send request to server (flask). Flask should generate partial HTML or JSON with data from database and send it (the same way as full HTML). JavaScript will get it and it has to replace this in HTML in browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

The first thing I would do would be to define an address in Flask that send the information that you want to the browser.

```
@app.route('/get_info')
def get_info():
    df = query_your_db()
        return df.to_json(orient = 'split')
```

And in javascript I would call this address when I press de button like this:

```
function render_info() {
  console.log('render_info()');
  $.post('get_info', function(data_json) 
    {
        window.info= JSON.parse(data_json);

        $('#name_div').append(info);
    }
    );
}
```

And the html button would be like this:

```
<a id="get_info_button" onclick="render_info()"></a>
```

Hope it helps you